# How to debug step by step C# code using Roslyn API

Tags: c#, debugging, roslyn

I am looking for example how to debug step by step C# script through Roslyn API.
It is quite easy to analyze and run C# code, eg:

```
var value = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("1 + 2").Result;
```

But how to debug the code using Rosyln API?

Comment: What do you mean by "debug the code"? Do you want to see the intermediate values of variables?

Comment: Good question! Intermediate values of variables for sure, but also have simple interface (like Step Over, Step Into) to naviagte through the code instructiuon by instruction no matter of the control logic (ifs, loops, etc).

Comment: Roslyn doesn't supply a debugging API. Even in Visual Studio we just write out PDBs and the actual stepping is taken care of by the debugging engine.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski - perhaps you can link to some steps for that?

Comment: @StingyJack: no idea. How our debugging system works is a mystery to me. :-)

Comment: Was an answer found for this?